# How to deploy two zipped Functions to the same Azure Function App?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I trying to deploy two zipped Functions to the same Azure Function App called `http-trigger-api-test` and the result is that the first one gets deployed but then it is replaced by the second function.

I have the tasks in the following yaml file:

```
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage for Azure Function
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    steps:

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive HttpTriggerApi Azure Function'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: 'azure/azure_functions/HttpTriggerApi/function_code'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive HttpTriggerApiWeb Azure Function'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: 'azure/azure_functions/HttpTriggerApi/function_code_web'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)2.zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      displayName: 'Upload Azure Function Full Stack'
      artifact: full_stack_deploy

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)2.zip
      displayName: 'Upload Azure Function Web Stack'
      artifact: web_deploy

- stage: TEST
  displayName: Deploy stage Test
  variables:
  - group: optimizelyeventconnector-test-group    
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: optimizelyeventconnector-test
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
       deploy:
        steps:

       - task: AzureCLI@1
        displayName: 'Deploy Azure Function Full Stack'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'test-group-SPN'
          scriptType: 'ps'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
            az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g test-group -n http-trigger-api-test --src $(Pipeline.Workspace)/full_stack_deploy/$(Build.BuildId).zip

      - task: AzureCLI@1
        displayName: 'Deploy Azure Function Web Stack'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'test-group-SPN'
          scriptType: 'ps'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
            az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g test-group -n http-trigger-api-test --src $(Pipeline.Workspace)/web_deploy/$(Build.BuildId)2.zip
```

I have read some questions where it is suggested not to pack several functions into one function app unless they are related. In my case, both functions are related.

Any suggestion, comment or improvement to this questions is welcome.

Comment: This is an expected behavior,  can't you have the two functions in the same assembly/class? check this out https://azurelessons.com/azure-how-many-functions-in-one-function-app/#:~:text=Yes%2C%20You%20can%20keep%20multiple,like%20below%20inside%20one%20class.&text=You%20can%20keep%20multiple%20Azure%20Functions%20inside%20one%20class%20like,Function%20for%20each%20case%20instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the solution.

I had to structure my function app in the following way:

```
- main_function_app
  - functions
    - Full_Stack
        - configAPI.json
        - configAPITest.json
        - function.json
        - index.js
    - Web  
        - configAPI.json
        - configAPITest.json
        - function.json
        - index.js
    - host.json
    - local.settings.json
    - package-lock.json
    - package.json
    - proxies.json
    - utils.js
```

When deploying to azure, you need to install node, dependencies, zip the files and publish them.

```
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage for Azure Function
  jobs:
    - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
           vmImage: $(vmImageName)
steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '14.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'npm install --prefix azure/azure_functions/HttpTriggerApi/main_function_app/functions'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Build Azure Functions and Dependencies'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: 'azure/azure_functions/HttpTriggerApi/main_function_app/functions'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: zip
    archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
  displayName: 'Publish Azure Functions Artifact'
  artifact: functions
```